# document.write XHTML error » h1 not allowed

Tags: javascript, xhtml, document.write

as I'm using Cufon's on my website, but also want to make it look good with JavaScript disabled, I decided to use

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.write("<h1 class='naam'><a class='naam' href='mysite.nl'>MyName</a></h1>");
</script>
<noscript>
    <h1 class='other_mockup'><a class='naam' href='mysite.nl'>MyName</a></h1>
</noscript>
```

This works fine. However, when I validate it, I get this error:

> document type does not allow element "h1" here

What to do to fix this? :(

Comment: Need more context. Post the whole document.

Comment: Is the `h1` in a `p` element by any chance?

Comment: @pimvdb wouldn't the `<h1>` implicitly close a `<p>`? Well I guess we'd need to know the doctype to be sure.

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, but as he states it works fine. The error seems to come from the W3 validator.

Comment: Well, this is pretty much the only context. The H1 isn't in a <p>. However, maybe there is an other way than using cufons? http://tejpotter.com/ « that website, for example, uses some kind of cufon, but without using JavaScript, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking through my old question and saw that this one still wasn't solved.

If you want to do the same, use @fontface ( CSS ).

To use it, go to [this website](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). It is really easy to install and works better than Cufon's.

Answer (score 2):

See the specification for [differences in script and style elements from HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8).

You can't use `<` and `>` as data in scripts without some form of escape.

> This works fine.

Then you are probably serving the document as `text/html` instead of `application/xhtml+xml` so browsers are treating it as HTML.